# A Different Color for "Thanks for your edit" message

Tags: discussion, edits, design, suggested-edits

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Pic1]

---

When mixed with a question that uses quotes starting with the `>` character, the "Thanks for your edit" message might be accidentally interpreted as part of the original post.

---

A random example of why it might be confusing:

[image: Pic2]

---

You might say: Yeah... Just read what it says and you will realize it's not part of the actual post...

---

Previous suggestion:

What I'm suggesting is to make it differentiable at first sight. Something like this could work:

[image: Pic3]
*(Ignore the different font type and color please, it's a very rough example)*

---

Newest suggestion:

I just realized using/modifying this message could solve the problem very well:

[image: Pic4]

This is the message displayed after editing a documentation. It is displayed in the top right-hand corner, which may or may not be better.

---

**Benefits:**

1. Instantly distinguishable from the other quote(s).
2. I also think it should be changed to green since that is the standard color for good things happening in StackExchange (accepted question color, earn reputation color, etc.), and it's more soothing as a thank you message.

Comment: Hmm... not sure green would work on all sites. On MathOverflow, the accepted answer is already colored green while quote/edit color is grey, as you can see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/145824).

Comment: But now that you know that that message exists, will it ever be confusing to you again? It seems like for the few times this might confuse somebody, it'll resolve itself very quickly with no style change necessary. (Btw re: above comment, yeah, not globally green, you'd want a site-specific color for it, but, that doesn't really impact your suggestion of course.)

Comment: @Laurel I guess it can be customized into other colors, depending on the site too. Edit: and JasonC also suggested that already, I didn't read his post first, oops.

Comment: @JasonC I don't personally get confused by this, I'm just saying it from a new user's perspective. Why have the confusion the first time if it can be avoided?

Comment: So... you're saying there's a problem when there may not actually be a problem? I'm sorry... No.

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq I don't recall a case of anybody being confused by this then mentioning it here in the past, although I don't read every meta post. Did you see a new user make a comment about it somewhere that prompted this?

Comment: I would say, the newest suggestion looks pretty cool :)

Comment: I'm not in favor of the third opinion because it's more like a tool-tip, which could be dismissed via a cross button. I would like a more *persistent* notification which only gets removed when the edited post gets live for all users, but not before that.